# why do functions dont have parameterized return types, as it has parameterized input?

Tags: java, function, return-type

This always forces us to return a single parameter in case I need to return multiple, say a List and a String. This restriction is not there in function arguments.

Comment: Can you show us some code to describe what you want to do?

Comment: If we want to pass a List and a String to a function, we can do it as process(List, String). 

If we want to return a String and List, I have to Create an Object with String and List as parameters and return the Object.

Comment: @Techmaddy - Its game going on here.... I will ask this question, and then you come and answer, I will accept your answer.... How naive!! Please don't pollute.

Comment: Doesn't Java have an pendant to "out"/"ref"-parameters in C#?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This problem is what functional languages such as F#, haskell etc. attempt to address.  The problem is that in hardware, a function's return value was originally returned via a CPU register, so you could only return a single value.  C syntax passed on this legacy and C++ (and C#, Java) also inherited this.

Comment: If it is possible with python, then I think hardware limitation may not be a problem. If it is there in Java/CPP it will be really useful.

Comment: As I said, syntactical sugar. I can't see any benefit or usefulness, but yes I am seeing coding nightmare, bad practices, and lot of refactoring.

Comment: This is for accumulator-based CPU architectures?

Comment: Which is originally what C was written for on UNIX...

Now we have much more knowledge regarding programming languages and make sacrifices in performance for gains in programmer efficacy and efficiency :)

Answer (score 4):

In fact, some languages do what you exactly want. For example Python, look at this code. It returns 2 values: 1 string and another int.

```
>>> def myFunc():
...   string_val = "techmaddy"
...   int_val = 10
...   return string_val, int_val
...
>>>
>>> s, i = myFunc()
>>>
>>> print s
techmaddy
>>>
>>> print i
10
```

I hope it would help.

PS: Under the covers, I guess Python is boxing it in a list and un-boxing it. I don't know Python that well to tell you what exactly it does.

Comment: Syntactical sugar, I would say.

Comment: @Vinegar: but oh-so-sweet syntactical sugar at that.

Comment: @Srikanth - Its game going on here.... I will ask this question, and then you come and answer, I will accept your answer.... How naive!! Please don't pollute.

Comment: Python does box the return values in a tuple and unbox them. Technically, it's not even implicit (I think) because something like string_val, int_val creates a tuple even without parentheses.

Comment: Ya Spence one is appropriate for C, C++, Java and C#. This one is more appropriate example, as I was expecting.

Comment: @Srikanth- Yeah, but he already know whose answer is to accept. Just be honest for your own sake. One will get the reputation but lose the soul.

Comment: @Vinegar: I really don't know whether to laugh and leave it or to answer you, again. Losing my soul? What did I say? If I were to be asking this question, I would take Spence's answer. I voted Spence's answer up so that it stays at the top. What can I do if he takes my answer?

Comment: @Vinegar: Thanks for the time that you spent for this question. I agree the point that you mentioned that I have added this to Java tag. So, I am going with Spence's answer. Otherwise I am not trying to pollute this. The Python example was more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks you Srikanth and Techmaddy. I really appreciate you both, that you guys clear my doubt. And +1 for the answer and the question.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to do this frequently enough, then create a class just to hold the result and return that instead.

This also allows you to DOCUMENT what your function returns in the same way that the parameters are documented.

Answer (score 3):

or, return Object[] from your method, and do

```
return new Object[] { list, string};
```

If you need more parameterized return types, you could create Pair<X,Y> classes, or Triplet<Z,Y,Z> and return those.

Comment: Its a single product, so are all of your given options. I hope now it makes sense.

Comment: Ya, this is a solution. And I was wondering why the language don't have the feature of parametrized return type. 

Here the Problem is the return type cannot be controlled. It is dynamic. So normally another way is to define a Object with List and String with setters and getters.

Comment: Its a single return type, think of method declaration.

Comment: The problem with returning an untyped list is you lose all type safety.  And creating a return object whose sole purpose in life is to pass a return value from a function is ugly.

Shame your not in C#, they've used out and ref parameters to try and deal with this.

Comment: Wow a downvote?  That's harsh.  It was a java question, these are java possible "workarounds".  I see that the formatter stripped out my greaterthan/s, so that doesn't help.  it was Pair<?,?>.  Yes, they aren't the best solution, but they work.  Your other option is to use a different language...

Answer (score 1):

Javascript, fortunately for you, is a dynamic language. This means you can construct any kind of object you want and return it. This effectively meets your requirement of having a "parameterized" return value, albeit in a rather un-typesafe way.

For example:

```
function stuff() {
    return {
        "foo": "a",
        "bar": "b"
    }
}

var theStuff = stuff();
alert(theStuff.foo + theStuff.bar); // should output "ab"
```

Answer (score 0):

On way to handle complex return behaviour is to pass an interface which the method calls.
e.g.

```
public interface Results<R> {
    public void processing(String stage);
    public void success(String mesg, R result);
    public void successes(String mesg, List<R> result);
    public void thrown(Throwable t);
}

public void process(Results<R> results, String text, List<String> data);
```